# Do .Net Assemblies (Class Libraries) compiled in debug mode slow performance on ASP.NET when DEBUG=FALSE in web.config

Tags: asp.net

I have read Scott Guthie's article  [Don’t run production ASP.NET Applications with debug=”true” enabled](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/11/Don_1920_t-run-production-ASP.NET-Applications-with-debug_3D001D20_true_1D20_-enabled.aspx)  but I am still not sure if we compile class libraries in debug mode that are referenced by our asp.net web site (and are in the Bin directory) does this affect performance or are they recompiled as non debug? We have DEBUG=FALSE set in our web.config.

Thanks
Richard

Comment: You need to compile the dll in release mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An assembly compiled as debug will have debug instrumentation in it. It will be slower and larger than a release build. Your ASP.NET site has no control over the assembly itself.